# AngularJS 1.3 Migration Not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

I have updated my script code to the following after reading about documentation on migrating from *`1.2`* to *`1.3`*.

```
var app = angular.module("APP", []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.id = [{
    id: 'id #1'
}];

$scope.addNewId = function () {
    var newId = $scope.id.length + 1;
    $scope.id.push({
        'id': 'id #' + newId
    });
};

$scope.removeId = function (index) {
    if (index >= 1) {
        $scope.id.splice(index, 1);
    }
};

});
```

This is the code for the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en" ng-app = "APP">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Add New ID</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "form.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <section>
        <h1>Add New Stuff</h1>
            <form name = "form" id = "form">
            <div ng-model = "indiv">
                <fieldset class="ids" data-ng-repeat="indiv in id">
                    <legend>ID</legend>

                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="60">&nbsp

                    <label for="age">Age:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" size="60">&nbsp

                    <button type="button" name="lookup" id="lookup">LOOKUP</button>&nbsp


                    <button class="remove" ng-click="removeId($index)">Remove ID</button><br>
                </fieldset>

                <br>
                <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewId()">Add ID</button>

            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" id = "submit" value="SUBMIT">
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
```

It is supposed to add a new set of input fields to a form. Please help

Comment: I can not see any `form` here !!!

Comment: Maraboc I just added it!

Comment: I think you must switch `<fieldset class="ids" data-ng-repeat="indiv in id">` with `<div ng-model = "indiv">` ??!!

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by switch? Or do you mean replace?

Comment: is this your actual code? because I see an `</form>` I don't see the opening `<form>` tag....

Comment: also, the `ng-model="indiv"` is out of scope, because you are declaring `indiv` as the product of the `ng-repeat` inside the `div` (besides the fact that having `ng-model` makes no sense).

Comment: No I tried to modify it to make it simplier for yall to correct, and I accidently deteted the opening <form> tag. Now it is added again.

Comment: I think your `ng-model` should be on the fieldset and the `ng-repeat` should be on the div.

Comment: looking at this, however, I can't see how this would have worked in 1.2, so the title suggesting that your problem is with migrating from 1.2 to 1.3 is at best not helpful, at worst misleading.  Nothing in this code is 1.2 or 1.3 specific.

Comment: Also, I fail to actually see something wrong here? I copied this code as written to plunker and the code seems to do what you state it is supposed to (adds new fieldsets).  http://plnkr.co/edit/p0aLeU3bIXUaeChUXcO8?p=preview

Comment: If you copy the code into a text editor and open it in a browser, it will not work

Comment: well that's true, you need a server for loading scripts from a separate file.  That doesn't have anything to do with the logic in your code, or changing from angular 1.2 to 1.3, it has to do with how HTML works.  And it's not an error, and not something we can tell you how to fix, short of putting all your scripts in the same document, or using a web server.

Answer (score 0):

An id attribute can't contain space nor sharp character here you are setting :

```
{id: 'id #1'}
```

May be a part of the answer if you're attributing this value to the id of each input in your ng-repeat.

can you show us the form ?

Comment: Just did. Please help. Thank you

Comment: first you're calling `ng-click="removeID($index)"` it's removeId($index) with a lowercase "d". then you have to set an ng-model attribute on your input to retrieve their value. An important thing though, you can't use static ids and names attribute for your inputs in an ng-repeat or you'll not be able to retrieve their values. Try : `<label for="age-{{$index}}">Age:</label><input type="text" name="age-{{$index}}" id="age-{{$index}}" size="60">`

Comment: Thank you but that didn't work. Also I fixeed removeId

Comment: it also miss the opening `<form>` tag. and the `<div ng-model="indiv">`  is a non-sense. ng-model had to be bind on input, select or textarea tags. An important thing to know, in Angular you don't submit form like in usual HTML. You have to bind each elements of your form with ng-model and call an action on a button tag, for example : `<buttont ng-click="submit()">submit</button>` and define a submit function in you controller : `$scope.submit = function(){...};`